# Woocommerce Subscription Manually Payment

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway, subscription

Is it possible to allow the user to choose manually payment if the payment gateway support Automatic Recurring Payments when buying a subscription? For example with a checkbox or something else?

Thank you for the help!

Best regards,
Mark

Comment: U mean Cash on delivery ... recurring payment... ?

Comment: When a user buy a subscription with Automatic Recurring Payments gateway. The system automatically deduct the money every months. I would like to add an option for the user to decide this automatically payment.